# Open download file after completion of Notification

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

I have used the notification to show the status of download file.I have simply used the FileOutputStream to download file , so that It can work also on API less than 9. But Now my problem is that after completion of download , I was trying to open that file in the corresponding reader. But it throws exception for window leaked If i close the application, in between of downloading file.

My progress update method code is below, please help me to come out from this.

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    progressUpdate(values[0]);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void progressUpdate(int percentageComplete) {
    CharSequence contentText = percentageComplete + "% complete";
    mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(mContext, mContentTitle, contentText,
            mContentIntent);            
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);

    if(percentageComplete==100){

        try {
            Log.e("file path ",file.getAbsolutePath());
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
            notificationIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(notificationIntent);
            finish();

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Unable to open file ,PDF Reader application is not installed in your device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Android gave windowlink error when activity finished and you want open dialog or any view provider want attach to window.

Answer (score 1):

After your app is in background or closed you should not show toast/dialogs. You can handle this from onPause() method of Activity lifecycle, take a boolean and set it to true on onPause(). If its true means your app is in background and you should not show dialogs.